# How do I change the default playout device on Mac Native WebRTC?

Tags: windows, macos, webrtc

I'm using WebRTC (Native Mac & Native Windows -- not JS) and am trying to change the default playout and recording devices and am having a lot of trouble. This is starting to drive me nuts since it *should* be very simple.

**Question:** What's the recommended way to change audio playout and recording devices while a call is ongoing on Mac & Windows, natively?

Here's what I've tried:

## Method 1

### Mac

I noticed the audio device module listens to Core Audio API notifications and adjusts playout and recording devices properly. This works, but I'm not sure if this is the recommended way to change devices.

### Windows

I was not able to find a system-wide way of setting the default audio playout/recording device. The only way I could tell *MIGHT* work is by getting a reference to the audio device module and calling `SetPlayoutDevice` / `SetRecordingDevice` on it manually...which leads to Method 2 below:

## Method 2

### Mac

If possible, I'd rather use `SetPlayoutDevice` ([link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+blame/HEAD/modules/audio_device/mac/audio_device_mac.cc#811)) / `SetRecordingDevice` ([link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+blame/HEAD/modules/audio_device/mac/audio_device_mac.cc#884)) to change the audio input/output (so Mac & Windows work the same way).

The [unit tests](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/HEAD/modules/audio_device/audio_device_unittest.cc#822) to test real audio IO devices shows we should be able to call `StartPlayout` and `StopPlayout` after a call to `SetPlayoutDevice` -- but this makes my app freeze. I've tried it without the call to `StopPlayout` and `StartPlayout` however it doesn't seem to do anything. This makes sense since it looks like only internal state is modified but nothing is modified.

Q: How can I change the default audio playout device and recording device on Mac?

### Windows

I haven't had a chance to try this out on Windows yet, but Mac not working makes me think there's something I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this myself.

VoEHardwareImpl (https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/stable/webrtc/+/refs/heads/master/voice_engine/voe_hardware_impl.cc) seems to have some relevant code.

For playout:

- StopPlayout
- ...set device index...
- StereoPlayoutIsAvailable
- SetStereoPlayout
- InitPlayout
- StartPlayout

For recording:

- StopRecording
- ...set device index...
- StereoRecordingIsAvailable
- SetStereoRecording
- InitRecording
- StartRecording

Depending on the commit you're on, you might need to ensure you won't get into a deadlock situation. Some of these methods acquire locks so make sure the lock isn't acquired yet if you're calling a method that requires locks. Better yet -- do this a level above or wrap the adm if possible.